# Get screen pixel color linux python3

Tags: python, linux, gtk, linux-mint

I have a working program in python 2.7 that I am trying to convert to python 3.3.

The working version is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import gtk.gdk
import sys

def PixelAt(x, y):
  w = gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window()
  pb = gtk.gdk.Pixbuf(gtk.gdk.COLORSPACE_RGB, False, 8, 1, 1)
  cm = w.get_colormap()
  pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w, cm, x, y, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  return pb.pixel_array[0][0]

print(PixelAt(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))
```

The partly converted one is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GdkPixbuf
import sys

def PixelAt(x, y):
  w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
  pb = GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new(GdkPixbuf.Colorspace.RGB, False, 8, 1, 1)
  cm = w.get_colormap()                              # What goes here?
  pb = pb.get_from_drawable(w, cm, x, y, 0, 0, 1, 1) # What goes here?
  return pb.pixel_array[0][0]

print(PixelAt(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2])))
```

What do I need to finish converting?

[EDIT]

Thanks to @jku here is my complete python3 color picker:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Print RGB color values of screen pixel at location x, y
from gi.repository import Gdk
import sys

def PixelAt(x, y):
  w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
  pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(w, x, y, 1, 1)
  return pb.get_pixels()

print(tuple(PixelAt(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))))
```

[END-EDIT]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(w, x, y, 1 ,1)
```

that should do it. Note that `pixbuf_get_from_window()` can return None just like the Gdk2 function you used: you must check the return value before using it.

Comment: Thank you much @jku! I added my final complete program in my post edit.