# Get color pixel screen - linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, colors, screen

I found a topic to get pixel color of my screen.
[Get screen pixel color linux python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27395968/get-screen-pixel-color-linux-python3) and [How can I grab the color of a pixel on my desktop? (Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605350/how-can-i-grab-the-color-of-a-pixel-on-my-desktop-linux)

I modified the code to put the gdkversion in, something which should be required.
This is my code now (python 3.6.9, with linux mint):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# Print RGB color values of screen pixel at location x, y
import gi
gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gdk
import sys

def PixelAt(x, y):
  w = Gdk.get_default_root_window()
  pb = Gdk.pixbuf_get_from_window(w, x, y, 1, 1)
  return pb.get_pixels()

print(tuple(PixelAt(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))))

PixelAt(10, 10)
```

But when I run the code in terminal, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(tuple(PixelAt(int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The code I used  (from link above is like 6 years old), so maybe something changed. Can someone help me out?

In the end I look for a working solution to get a pixel color of a certain location of my screen on a linux (mint) machine.

Comment: Please show the command line you are using to run the program.

Comment: if you tell me how to add command line. i will do. image is added. How crucial was this image for you to help me?

Comment: `sys.argv` are the command line args. You have not provided any args on the command line so it means you are not running it correctly. Pass in pixel coordinates on the command line or change that line of code.

Comment: forgive me, but under my print statement, there is a command which requests " PixelAt(10,10)".

Why would this not work? Could you please provide more explanation how i should transform the code to make it work?

Comment: Well, the `print` statement comes first so it executes before the `PixelAt(10,10)`. So if the `print` statement causes the program to terminate (which it does) it should be obvious that it will not even get to the `PixelAt(10,10)` statement.